# Tooltip on SetTimeout only show on mouse move

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the **Cool DHTML tooltip script** from **© Dynamic Drive DHTML code library**. I use this script to show a tooltip I have made.

Given that I don't want to show the Tooltip instantly, I have added simple code to the script :

1. When the **mouse enter** the div, I set a variable to true and I start a SetTimeout of 0,5 second.
2. **After the delay** of 0,5 second, I verify if the variable is still set to `True`, if yes, I show the Tooltip.
3. If I **leave the div**, I set the variable to `False`. So, the tooltip will not show if you leave the div.

*Code :*

**1*** :

```
ifenter = true;
...
setTimeout(function () {
    if (ifenter == true) {
        enabletip = true
    } else {

    }
}, 500);
```

**2*** :

```
if (ifenter == true) {
enabletip = true
} else {

}
```

**3*** :

```
ifenter = false;
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKyPs/7/).

The problem is after the 0,5 second, the Tooltip will show only if you move the mouse.

I tried to find a solution but I didn't find no fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set enabletip to true, it has no effect on the actual display of the tooltip, you need to call positiontip right after to have the display done.
But to have the coordinates where to put the tooltip, you have to handle the mouseover (ShowHint) 'properly', i.e. take e as argument to have the current coordinates.

I updated your fiddle this way and it works. Notice i hooked the event handler in the code, at the end.

http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/jKyPs/15/

```
var thetitle = 'test title' , thetext =' test text';

function ShowHint(e) {

 //... same code to handle useless browsers ...

 setTimeout(function () {
    if (ifenter == true) {
        enabletip = true;
                    positiontip ( { pageX : e.pageX, pageY : e.pageY } );
                } 
            }, 500);
```

Comment: I can't see your change, can you give me the link ? please :)

Comment: what if user move mouse quickly out of the element, say in less than half second?  you forgot to clear  timeout.

Comment: Just noticed `Vincent Piel` and `Vinc P` look so similar names :D

Comment: @Moazzam Khan  :the test using 'isenter' is here to adress this case.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it could be using this logic -

```
var timeoutid=null;
var isShowing = false;
function showTooltip(){
    //show the tooltip code goes here
    isShowing=true;
}

function hideTooltip(){
    //hide tooltip code goes here
    isShowing=false;
}

/* el is the element on which you want a tooltip */
el.onmouseover = function(){
    timeoutid = setTimeout(showTooltip, 500);
}

el.onmouseout = function(){
   clearTimeout(timeoutid);
   if(isShowing)hideTooltip();
}
```

And if you want to update position of tooltip on mouse movement -

```
el.onmousemove = updateTooltipPosition;

function updateTooltipPosition(e){
 // logic to update goes here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I still have to move the mouse... http://jsfiddle.net/jKyPs/16/

Comment: @Vinc P. you just copied it. It wasn't a complete solution, it was a way to solve it.